# Django: user profile creation forms

Tags: python, django, forms, models

As I've understood the deal, the standard way of extending the `User` Django model is by implementing `profiles`.

This suits me wonderfully, since I have 3 types of profiles (3 different `Model` subclasses) all based upon the `User` model for uniqueness and authentication.

I'm having trouble deciding, however, on the best way of implementing a user creation form. Should I...

1. Use mixins: inherit a `ModelForm` with `model=User` and one with `model=Profile`, manually overriding `save()` and `clean()` to call the bases' methods and perform the foreign key assignment.
2. Use composition: inherit `Form` and manually instantiate and manage two `ModelForms`.
3. Instantiate the forms separately, and `save()` them in a manually ordered fashion.
4. The Best Way I Didn't Think Of.

I would appreciate a (however minimal) implementation so I can be sure I'm making the right calls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are trying to customize user model ?

Comment: that, I already have. I'm trying to create a Profile and a User using the same Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a single form that acts as a combined ModelForm for both your Profile model and the contrib User model. To accomplish this, a little manipulation of the forms kwargs on init is required. See this snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2081/

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, though the answer got to me too late :(. I'll post my implementation for reference afterwards. Thanks a lot!